# API function to find username of shared files or folders on network in c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

With the help of NetFileEnum or Openfiles.exe  of system32, we can get the username who has opened the shared files.  Is there any API function or any exe files in any programming language like c#, vb.net, visual c++ to find out who is the user to create, rename, or delete shared files or folders on the network?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, it will give you access rights information on a file

```
string fileName = @"C:\Text.txt";

FileSecurity oFSec = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
AuthorizationRuleCollection oARC = oFSec.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule oFSAR in oARC)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User : " + oFSAR.IdentityReference.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Access Control Type : " + oFSAR.AccessControlType.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("File System Rights : " + oFSAR.FileSystemRights.ToString());
}
```